# Switch between view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want programatically switch from one view controller to another. I use the following code :

```
SenderPlayerViewController *myViewController = [[SenderPlayerViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

but I get a black screen, while I have already put some controls in `SenderPlayerViewController`.

Comment: It is the right way to do it. Your mistake must be somewhere else. Also, do not forget to release myViewController after pushing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are u trying to instantiate with an nib file? If so, you must use [`initWithNibName:bundle:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
SenderPlayerViewController *myViewController = [[SenderPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SenderPlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Also with a story board it is not enough to call alloc init on a controller class.

It should be something like

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SenderPlayerViewController"];
```

Comment: I use what you said and I get an error : Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0xb175570>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SenderPlayerViewController

Comment: so u got some other issue. by the informations u gave us, we won't be able to help u further.

Comment: OK the problem solved!

I filled the property "Identifier" in the Interface Builder with the name of the View Controller "SenderPlayerViewController".

Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a view controller from a storyboard you should use

```
SenderPlayerViewController *myViewController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheNameOfYourController"]
```

instead of alloc init.

Comment: funny, I got the impression, I just wrote that 25 minutes earlier.